# How do I import across submodules

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing

We've got a test framework using nose and factory_boy up and going.

As recommended, we've put a /test directory inside of each module directory and that's where we put a factories.py file and the various test cases.

The challenge I've got is trying to import factories and functions between these test submodules.  Full code branch is here:

https://github.com/bethlakshmi/GBE2/tree/GBE-471

In case I haven't relayed enough detail to be useful.

### Detailed problem

The summary of the relevant structure is:

```
/gbe
    __init__.py
    tests.py
    (many more files)
    /tests
         __init__.py
         factories.py
         functions.py
         (many files of tests, all tests_*)
/ticketing
    __init__.py
    tests.py
    /tests
         __init__.py
         factories.py
         test_edit_event.py
```

It's in that last folder that problem is happening.

I can't seem to import anything from gbe.tests and I want to reuse the mocks provided in factories.py and the functions in functions.py

Whatever I try, consistently results in the form of either:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/bethlakshmi/Documents/mysite/GBE2/expo/ticketing/test/test_edit_event.py", line 27, in setUp
self.privileged_user = gbe_tests.factories.ProfileFactory.create().user_object
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'factories'
```

or something similar to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 420, in loadTestsFromName
      addr.filename, addr.module)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
      return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
      mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
    File "/Users/bethlakshmi/Documents/mysite/GBE2/expo/ticketing/test/test_edit_event.py", line 12, in <module>
      import gbe.tests.factories as gbe_fact

    ImportError: No module named factories
```

### Things I've tried:

- various variations on "from gbe.tests import functions, factories"
- various forms of "import gbe.tests as gbe_test" and rename the calls to the factories and functions accordingly.
- messing with the **init**.py file to import there, or to set the **all** to functions.py and factories.py

The command I'm trying to run is:

./manage.py test ticketing

As far as I can tell, to the code, the internal contents of gbe.tests just doesn't exist.  I have no problem importing gbe.models, gbe.views, gbe.functions, etc.  Nor do I have a problem with anything in /ticketing

I've read every question in stackoverflow that I can find with no success.

90% of the accepted answers seem to be "make sure you have an **init**.py" - which is already true in my case.

I also tried messing with the system path, with no success.

### Note:

You'll see that I repeated the factories I want to mock in the ticketing/tests/factories.py - that's the only way I can get the tests in ticketing to run, and I refuse to have broken tests in a check-in if I can help it.

I've tried removing those classes, and the errors above prevail - when I CAN refactor to remove this redundant code, I will do so with great joy.

### Final Question

What am I missing?

Comment: Presumably a circular dependency; are the tests both importing each others' factories?

Comment: same here, first thought was circular dependency: does anything in `gbe` app import from `ticketing` ?

Comment: gbe imports from ticketing, but not from ticketing/tests - gbe.models imports from ticketing.models and ticketing.models imports from gbe.models - and that hasn't been a problem in a year of development and manual integration test.  Why would that matter when ticketing/tests is trying to import from gbe/tests?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your package structure:

```
/gbe
    __init__.py
    tests.py
    /tests
         __init__.py
         factories.py
         functions.py
```

You have a file `tests.py` and a package `tests`. Now when you want to `from gbe.tests import x` python interpreter doesn't know whether you want to import from the file or the package and by default will try to import from the file.

To fix the problem I suggest you move and rename your `tests.py` to the `tests` package.

Note that the convention is to put tests folder outside the main application folder though, like for example [flask](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask) does. Personally I use below structure for my tests:

```
/tests
    /my_app
        test_views.py
    /integration
    /factories
    /fixtures
        mocks.py
/my_app
    views.py
```

So I have a `tests/my_app` folder where I replicate the structure of the my_app - I put unit tests only there.
I also have `tests/integration` folder where I don't replicate the structure of my_app - I use different naming there.
I group my factories classes and fixtures in a separate folders and I can use them in all my tests if I want to.

Comment: Thanks!  This was helpful and got my test working properly.  I have a review pending with my team... but failing other good answers, I suspect this is the winner.  Thank you!  Will mark accepted assuming team can't find an answer we all like better (personally, I'm a fan, but I like to hear other opinions).